# Laravel: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to loop through an array of ids to get data from another table, I mean I want to get latest queues of every schedule id we are looping in it.

So first i have **$schedules**:

> $schedules = [{"id":19},{"id":18},{"id":15}]

And the foreach loop is like this:

```
$queues= [];
foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
     $queues[] = Queue::withTrashed()
                     ->latest()
                     ->where('schedule_id', $schedule);
}
return $queues;
```

when i return queues it's showing :

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Comment: you are defining `$queueses = [];` and then you are using `$queues[] = Queue::...`. Is this a typo? Also, you are not running the query, you need a `->get()` at the end of `Queue::...->where(...)->get()`

Comment: thanks man, but i have another problem of getting only empty square brackets, and when i remove ->where('schedule_id', $schedule) this will work but is getting data that i dont want. what is wrong with that line of code @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: try with `->where('schedule_id', $schedule->id);`

Comment: umm, i dont think this will work, it just gotten worse, it's saying  `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`. is that suppose to appear? @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: if you are defining the variable `$schedules` and assigning it the value as it is shown in the question, try doing it this way: `$schedules = json_decode('[{"id":19},{"id":18},{"id":15}]');`

Comment: yup thanks man for ur help, that worked fine. @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error that shows is related to you are not running the query, you need a `->get()` at the end of `Queue::...->where(...)->get()` to do it.

if you dont do it, as Dhananjay Kyada say in his answer:

> it will try to return a query object

But to return a response:

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()
```

Next, we need to tackle one more thing.

If you are defining the variable `$schedules` and assigning it the value as it is shown in the question:

> $schedules = [{"id":19},{"id":18},{"id":15}]

try to do it taking the JSON as string and converting it into a PHP variable with [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$schedules = json_decode('[{"id":19},{"id":18},{"id":15}]');
```

Then you can use the id values in you where clause:

```
->where('schedule_id', $schedule->id)->get()
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you are not getting the result from your query. Because it is just a query it will return a query object. You need to add `->get()` in order to get the result. You can try the following code:

```
$queues = [];
foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
     $queues[] = Queue::withTrashed()
                 ->latest()
                 ->where('schedule_id', $schedule)->get()->toArray();
}
return $queues;
```